# c# model interprets mm:ss as hh:mm

Tags: c#, regex, attributes, date-format, displayformat

in my application i have a song class which has a property length and this looks like:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm\\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-6][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Time.")]
public TimeSpan? Length { get; set; }
```

so i want it to display mm:ss and it works like a charm
but as i want to validate my input that doesn't work as good. i also want the user to input the length as mm:ss, so that is forced by the regex. but my application interprets the minutes as hours and the seconds as minutes.

so when i enter 05:25, my length will be set to 05:25:00. how can i change this? i'm just a beginner so i appologize if this is a stupid question.
thanks in advance

Comment: `DisplayFormat` only affects the way the stored data is displayed. In particular, it **does not affect the way the entered data is parsed**. I'm afraid what you want to do cannot be done easily. I have closed this question as a duplicate of another one, whose answer explains exactly why this is the case.

Comment: When you enter `05:25` *where*? TimeSpan has no format, it's just a binary value. The problem is caused in whatever code you have that parses the input into a TimeSpan. Are you using data binding? You should set the format string on the data binding statement then